# Perfect Sets of Measure Zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that every perfect set in $\mathbb R$ has a perfect subset having Lebesgue measure $0$.
$$$$Let $P$ be a perfect set. If $P$ is not nowhere dense then we can find an open interval say $(a, b)$ such that $P$ is dense in this interval but as $P$ is closed hence contains this interval. Now we can chose points $c < d$ such that $[c, d] \subseteq (a, b)$. We can do the Cantor set construction of the closed interval $[c, d]$ to find a perfect set having measure $0$ and we are done. Now suppose that $P$ is nowhere dense. Let $A= \sup P$ and $B=\inf P$ then as $P$ is closed hence $A, B \in P$. Consider the closed interval $[A, B]$. Let us call a point $p$ isolated from right side of $P$ if there exists a $\delta > p$ such that $$(p, \delta) \cap P = \phi.$$ Now if $C \in [A, B]$ is right isolated point of $P$ then the set $$P \cap [A, C]$$ is a perfect set as the set is closed and any limit point of $P$ is also a limit point of $[A, C]$. Consider the set $$X = (x \in [A, B] : x\text{  is a right isolated point of  }P ).$$ The set $X$ is non empty as $B \in X$ and as it is a bounded set so let $q = \inf X$. Now if $A < q$ then consider the interval $(A, q)$, as $P$ is nowhere dense hence there exists an open interval $(s, t) \subseteq (A, q)$ such that $$P \cap (s, t) = \phi.$$ Hence $s < q$ is a right isolated point of $P$, a contradiction hence $A = \inf P$ and hence we can find right isolated points of $P$ arbitrarily close to $A$. Hence we can find sets $P \cap [A, r]$ of arbitrarily small measure.

But I do not know how to proceed further??

Comment: The space is $R$ and the measure is Lebesgue

Comment: Why can't you just imitate the construction of the Cantor set? Find two disjoint perfect subsets of $P$, each having diameter at most $\frac13$. Next, inside each of those two sets, find two disjoint perfect sets of diameter at most $\frac19$. Etc. Doesn't that work?

Comment: Can you please give a full Proof?

Comment: I'm too lazy to do that. I prefer to give advice (good or bad) and let somebody else do the work.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is perfect then $P$ has at least two elements: $x_1,x_2\in P$, with $x_1<x_2$. Let $a=x_2-x_1$.

Since, $P$ is perfect, there exist $x_{3}, x_{4}\in P$, such that
$$
|x_1-x_{3}|<a/3, \quad
|x_2-x_{4}|<a/3
$$
Repeat the argument and find $x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8\in P$, such that
$$
|x_1-x_{5}|<a/9, \quad
|x_2-x_{6}|<a/9, \quad
|x_3-x_{7}|<a/9, \quad
|x_4-x_{8}|<a/9.
$$
In this way you construct a perfect set, namely the closure of $\{x_n\}$,
which is a subset of $P$ and has measure zero.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be a perfect subset of $\mathbb R$; I want to show that $P$ contains a perfect set of (Lebesgue) measure zero. (A perfect set is a **nonempty** closed set with no isolated points. I will write $\lambda$ for Lebesgue measure.)

Without loss of generality we can assume that $P$ is bounded, say $P\subseteq[a,b]$. Also, we can assume that $\lambda(P)\gt0$, otherwise there is nothing to prove. Then the map $f:[a,b]\to[0,1]$ defined by setting $f(x)=\frac{\lambda(P\cap[a,x])}{\lambda(P)}$ is continuous and surjective, and it's easy to see that the restriction of $f$ to $P$ is also continuous and surjective. (The complement of $P$, being an open set, is a union of open intervals, and it's clear from the definition that the function $f$ is constant on each of those intervals, so any value attained on the complement of $P$ is also attained on $P$.) Thus there is a continuous surjection from $P$ to $[0,1]$. Since there is also a continuous surjection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ ([Peano curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_curve)), there is a continuous surjection $g:P\to[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

For each $t\in[0,1]$ let $S_t=[0,1]\times\{t\}$; then $P$ is partitioned into continuum many pairwise disjoint uncountable closed sets $g^{-1}(S_t)$. By the [Cantor-Bendixson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)), every uncountable closed set contains a perfect set. It follows that $P$ contains continuum many pairwise disjoint perfect sets. Because of the additivity of Lebesgue measure, these cannot all have positive measure; all but countably many of them have measure zero.